# White screen of death to the backend page after adding wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've developed a customized post type to showcase testimonials. However, when I insert the shortcode in the webpage's backend and save it, the backend page turns white, rendering me unable to perform any actions. This issue only occurs on the page with the shortcode, but the frontend displays everything correctly.

Here is the shortcode:

```
function titan_testimonial_sliders_shortcode() {
    ob_start();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'testimonial',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all posts        
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Fetch only post IDs
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'slider_appearance',
                'value' => 'slide1',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'slider_appearance',
                'value' => 'slide2',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    );

    $titan_slider_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($titan_slider_query->have_posts()) {
        $titan_slider_one = '';
        $titan_slider_two = '';

        while ($titan_slider_query->have_posts()) {
            $titan_slider_query->the_post();

            ob_start();

            // Common HTML for both sliders
            ?>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="testimonial-card">
                    <div class="testimonial-card__avator">
                        <div class="t-avator">
                            <?php
                            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
                            } else {
                                if (get_field("name_initials")) {
                                    echo '<div>' . get_field("name_initials") . '</div>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial-card__content">
                        <h4 class="t-name"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <?php
                        if (get_field("organization")) {
                            echo '<span class="t-org">' . get_field("organization") . '</span>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div class="testimonial-content">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php

            $slide_content = ob_get_clean();

            // Sorting slides for different sliders
            if (get_field('slider_appearance') === 'slide1') {
                $titan_slider_one .= $slide_content;
            } else {
                $titan_slider_two .= $slide_content;
            }
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        // Output HTML for both sliders
        ?>
        <div class="swiper testimonial-slider-one">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <?php echo $titan_slider_one; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper testimonial-slider-two">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <?php echo $titan_slider_two; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('testimonial_sliders', 'titan_testimonial_sliders_shortcode');
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You have two `ob_start();` calls: one at the very top of your function and another one inside your `while(...)` loop.

Comment: Start by enabling WP debug mode and full PHP error reporting, and go check what the logs have to say.

Comment: `if(is_admin()){return;}` should make it just not run in the admin panel.

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you enough. I'm baffled as to why I didn't consider this earlier.